# Filter the data with specific dates - mern

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

Here I've dates (ie. updatedAt) with "2020-10-28T09:20:14.335Z" and "2020-10-30T09:20:35.086Z" . how can I filter the data with specific date (eg: 2020-10-28).

Data from server

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f9bdace778082303c859248",
        "createdAt": "2020-10-28T09:20:14.335Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-10-28T09:20:14.335Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f9bdae3778082303c859249",
        "createdAt": "2020-10-30T09:20:35.086Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-10-30T09:20:35.086Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

route: it gives empty array, how to make it work?

```
Attendance.find({ "updatedAt": { "$gte": "2020-10-28", "$lte": "2020-10-28" } })
.then(data => res.json(data))
.catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
```

route: but this works

```
Attendance.find({ "updatedAt": { "$gte": "2020-10-28T09:20:14.335Z", "$lte": "2020-10-28T09:20:14.335Z" } })
.then(data => res.json(data))
.catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can use aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "updatedAt": {
        "$substr": [
          "$updatedAt",
          0,
          10
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "updatedAt": {
        "$gte": "2020-10-28",
        "$lte": "2020-10-28"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Phfibnjm7Ov)**